# What's the distribution of the random variable ${F_X}^{-1}(U)$ where $U$ is a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X$ be a continuos random variable taking values in $[a,b]$ with c.d.f $F_X$ which is strictly increasing on $[a,b]

(a) Show that the random variable $F_X(X)$ has a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

(b) Let $U$ be a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$. What is the distribution of the random variable ${F_X}^{-1}(U)$ where ${F_X}^{-1}$ is the inverse of $F_X$?

It has been shown how to solve (a) in the answer to the question in the link below. However, I still don't know how to approach (b).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2277354/distribution-of-probabilities-of-the-circle-area-its-expectation-and-variance

Comment: This is an exercise in definitions. You need to know (show) that $F_U (x) = x$ for $x \in [0,1]$, $F_U(x) = 0$ for $x < 0$, and $F_U(x) = 1$ for $x > 1$. You'll also need to know that a continuous random variable is uniquely determined by its cumulative distribution function.